# Getting error when trying to get xml server response using jQuery.ajax & jsonp

Tags: ajax, jquery, jsonp, content-type

I'm trying to activate jQuery.ajax() request using jsonp and I'm getting the following error:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/xml

My request is:

```
return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: this.AgentServiceUrl + "/" + methodName,
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: 'jsonp', 
        success: function (json) {
            console.dir(json.sites);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
```

and the response I'm getting from the server is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 114
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2013 08:43:13 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://CosmoCom.com/WebServices/TCWS/Agent">010001</string>
```

What can I do?

Comment: I have the same problem... I MUST send out the POST request using ajax JSONP and can only get back XML... problem is its giving a parsererror

Answer (score 0):

As the error message rightly says, when you mark your datatype as jsonp. it means the data you will be receiving will be script. so you cant have your contenttype as "text/xml". 
Try changing it to **"application/json"** .

Also make sure that **your service is jsonp enabled**, meaning it returns data wrappped in a callback function.